# Does Samson believe that his super strength lies in his hair?

Tags: judges

Judges 16

> <sup>**17**</sup>Samson told her all that was in his heart: “My hair has never been cut, because I have been a Nazirite to God from my mother’s womb. If I am shaved, my strength will leave me, and I will become as weak as any other man.”
>
> <sup>**19**</sup>And having lulled him to sleep on her lap, she called a man to shave off the seven braids of his head. In this way she began to subdue him,d and his strength left him. 20Then she called out, “Samson, the Philistines are here!”
>
> When Samson awoke from his sleep, he thought, “I will escape as I did before and shake myself free.” But he did not know that the LORD had departed from him.

Why does Samson think that he still possesses super strength?

Comment: Which is the question: "*Does Samson believe that his super strength lies in his hair?*" or "*Why does Samson think that he still possesses super strength?*" ?

Answer (score 1):

Judges 16:

> 17 Samson told her **all** that was in his **heart**:

Samson did not lie. He told the truth. He really believed this.

> “My hair has never been cut, because I have been a Nazirite to God from my mother’s womb. If I am shaved, my strength will leave me, and I will become as weak as any other man.”

Being a Nazirite did not automatically give anyone super-strength.
God might have told him this bonus condition/covenant.

Does Samson believe that his super strength lies in his hair?

Yes, it was a belief from his very heart. It was the sign of the covenant/agreement.

> When Samson awoke from his sleep, he thought, “I will escape as I did before and shake myself free.” But he did not know that the LORD had departed from him.

Why does Samson think that he still possesses super strength?

He just woke up from his sleep. His thinking was hazy. He just remembered his previous occasions when he shook himself free. He did not know that the LORD had departed from him this time because he betrayed the covenant/agreement with God.
He revealed to Delilah the secret sign of the agreement with God.

Answer (score 1):

When Samson awoke, he did not know yet he was shaved. It is why he thought he can escape.

The text quoted in the question makes it clear: Samson did not wake up when he was shaved. He awoke only when she called him. So, he could not have known that he lost his hair.

Comment: I think adding more details and making a fully reasoned case is needed to make this an acceptable answer. We generally don't want one liners.

Answer (score -1):

Samson doesn't just believe alone, the Bible also bears witness that his hair is the secret of his strength.

*...So the secret of his strength was not known.*

Judges 16:9 (ESV):

> Now she had men lying in ambush in an inner chamber. And she said to him, “The Philistines are upon you, Samson!” But he snapped the bowstrings, as a thread of flax snaps when it touches the fire. So the secret of his strength was not known.

Why would he be so foolish as to believe that the Spirit of the Lord would rush upon him like before, even though the secret of his strength was cut off? He was subjected to Leviathan (Pride).

Job 41:34 (ESV):

> [Leviathan] He sees everything that is high;
> he is king over all the sons of pride.

What happens when Leviathan (pride) is your king? You take on your king's attributes and agenda.

Job 41:14 (ESV):

> Who can open the doors of his face [eyes and ears in this context]?
> Around his teeth is terror.

Job 41:18 (ESV):

> His sneezings flash forth light,
> and his eyes are like the eyelids of the dawn.

I interpret "eyelids of the dawn" as having one's eyes mostly closed to what is happening.

Here is a video commentary on Leviathan and the effects of this spirit in one's life.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kl1v9xUztKg